# Increase HTML progressbar position with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have a progressbar on my website and this is a part of its css:

```
.progress-bar span {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 25px;
    width: 78%; //the actual position

    -moz-border-radius: 3px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;

   //other css
}
```

I have to change the width that indicates the position of the progression (the line you see [here](http://prntscr.com/1mq8hu)). This is the first time I use progress bars and I have no idea about how to setup the javascript code.

Any advice? [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/WrYKf/)

Comment: can you please give us more information about your javascript code and the rest of your program / site / script ? (Maybe a small [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/))

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/WrYKf/ added

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the way [without jQuery](http://jsfiddle.net/Techsolo/WrYKf/1/)

HTML

```
<div  class="progress-bar" align="left">
    <span id="prog"></span>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var elem = document.getElementById("prog");
elem.style.width = "88%";
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using jQuery to make your javascript calls much simpler. You can download the latest version here: http://jquery.com/download/

First, include the jQuery file in the head of your html like this:

```
<head>
...
<script type="text/javascript" src="<location of file>jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
...
</head>
```

Then within your own javascript code, you can move the position of the progress bar like so:

```
jQuery('.progress-bar scan').css('width', <desired width>);
```

Hopefully that helps.

Comment: Is there a non jQuery way? +1

Comment: Sure, you can do it like this: 
 var elems = document.getElementsByTagName('span'), i;
 for (i in elems) {
        if(elems[i].parentNode.className === 'progress-bar') {
            elems[i].style.width = <desired width>;
        }
  }

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
document.querySelectorAll('.progress-bar span').forEach(function(elem) {
    elem.style.width = '<YOUR WIDTH>'; 
});
```

no jQuery

Answer (score 0):

I just incremented the width this way:

```
function increment(){
var width = document.getElementById('progressbar').clientWidth;
var divArray = document.getElementById('progressbar');
if(width<500){
var largura = width+10;
divArray.style.width = largura+'%';
setTimeout("increment()",1000);
}
else{
window.location.href = "http://www.google.com/";
}
}
```

And does it every second so it will be incremented every second but u can change it the way you want.